# Separate Cell with an Address into Multiple Columns in Excel Based on Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a column in Excel that has varied address information like so:

- 5 Kings Highway North, Suite 555 Cherry Hill, NJ 08043
       55 Split Rock    Dr. Cherry Hill, NJ 08003
       5555 Herbert St. Philadelphia, PA 19129

My question is if there is any way through formulas, text to columns, or VB to separate this information in to columns like this?

- 1 Column for Street Address

  1 Column for City, State, & Zip

I keep trying to think of a roundabout way, but can't seem to get the result I want with the extra address line in some but not all rows.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: do you alway have a comma or a point before the City name? and also after it? is this recurring feature?
can you please give a real screenshot of your data?

Comment: Those 3 examples at the top are verbatim how it is written. Let me see if I can get a screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I would first homogenize the data in your column ***A***, by replacing all the ***"."*** with ***","***, so that i have ***","*** as my separator between the chunks.
 then put this formula in the first cell of your address column ***C***:

```
=LEFT($A2,FIND(",",$A2)-1)
```

drag and fill down to find all the addresses.
then put this formula in the first cell under the City/Zip Code column ***D***:

```
=MID($A2,FIND(",",$A2)+2,LEN($A2))
```

and there you go!

***$A2*** is the first cell in column *A* where your data resides.
here is the example file where these formulas work , [downloadable from this file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61h64s4rntt5w2d/left_midfind.xlsx?dl=0)

 tell me if it doesnt, or you need more precision.

Comment: @user4326425 then please accept it as the answer to your question, check the tick mark below the answer counter.